# GIT: different hashes, but no differences between branches

Tags: git

I have 2 branches in my project (actually I have other branches for releases, but it doesn't matter here):

- master
- develop

Let's suppose `master`'s hash is X and `develop`'s is Y. There are no pending commits. Then, I merge `develop` into `master`, and I can check there are no files with differences between both branches. Why, after merging, `master`'s hash is still different to `develop`'s? I have other projects in which it does not occur, i.e., both hashes are equal after merging.

What may I have done to produce this effect? How can I achieve both hashes to be equal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you Joachim. Is there any way to "preview" a merge without performing it? I don't know if doing such merge would spoil the develop branch....

Comment: Ignore it.. I can create a new "test" branch from develop and merge master into it. I'll give it a try to see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want them both to be equal then a

```
git reset develop
```

while on the master branch will do it. There is a difference because the history is not the same. Look at your log to see where it is.